# min and max date on Datepicker won't work on my project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have an input field that isusing datepicker. I am trying to set it so the calendar shows as active only weekdays. past dates and dates 1 month ahead of the current date are aimed to be shown as inactive.

Currently, only the weekends are shown as inactive. The past dates are still shown as active.
Can someone please help me fix this?

```
<input id="date" type="text " class="form-control datepicker" name="date" value="Click to select a date">



$(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                maxDate: '+1m', //+1m is 1 month from now
                minDate: '0', //allow only from now on
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                orientation: 'auto'
            });
```

Comment: Works for me in terms of the range https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q8edsje9/

Comment: Any ideas why it won't work in my case?(Or why it works only partly?

Comment: Where do you see an option called `daysOfWeekDisabled`?

Comment: this shortcut won't specifically *disable* but this will only show weekdays. `.ui-datepicker-week-end{
  display: none;
}`  as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w96zhcrf/)

Comment: @j08691 OP is apparently using bootstrap datepicker.. based on his comment on the answer

Comment: can you make a demo of this via [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using a plugin or something, which you don't need if this is all you are doing. Try using the beforeShowDay parameter with noWeekends like:

```
      $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        maxDate: '+1m', //+1m is 1 month from now
        minDate: '0', //allow only from now on
        orientation: 'auto',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
      });
```

Above is jQuery's date picker. This is Bootstrap, so try using startDate/endDate something like:

```
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            endDate: '+1m', //+1m is 1 month from now
            startDate: '0', //allow only from now on
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            orientation: 'auto'
        });
```

Comment: All i am using is : <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok, you are using Bootstraps datepicker, not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If using bootstrap datepicker, try using startdate and enddate for date ranges:

[BootStrap enddate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate)

[Bootstrap startDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate)

Maybe something like this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
   startDate: 'now', //+1m is 1 month from now
   endDate: '+1m', //allow only from now on
   daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
   orientation: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: Ah, I think @fanfavorite beat me to it.